# Countif won't copy or update correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2007, countif

Ok, I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. I'm using Excel 2007 to count all cells that have numbers greater than zero. I type: =COUNTIF(A22:I22,">0"), and it counts everything just fine. However, when I paste the function to another row, it returns the same result as the previous row, even though that is not correct, and the function updates to reflect the new row.

Furthermore, when I change a number to zero in the reference range of the original (correctly functioning) formula, it does not update.

What could be going on?

Comment: Welcome! Questions here in stackoverflow must refer to a specific programming problem, please look for answers to this question in https://superuser.com/ before posting a duplicate in that site

Comment: Nonetheless...have you checked calculation is set automatic or manual?

Comment: It does look like your worksheet isn't being calculated. Check the *Calculation Options* on the Ribbon's *Formulas* tab. The `Automatic` option should be checked. Note that the option can be changed programmatically, and it's set for the Excel application. Therefore it's possible that you have a program running in another workbook, leaving the option set to *Manual* after a crash.

Comment: @RichieV Thanks for the info. I tried looking for a solution there, but I don't think I knew the right terms to use.

Comment: @Variatus That worked, thank you!